# what is ContextLoaderListener and Servlet context in a web application?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, web

Also can anyone explain this with reference to the statement mentioned below which was going through from spring-reference.

> If you do not want to use Spring's web MVC, but intend to leverage
>   other solutions that Spring offers, you can integrate the web MVC
>   framework of your choice with Spring easily. Simply start up a Spring
>   root application context through its ContextLoaderListener, and access
>   it through its ServletContext attribute (or Spring's respective helper
>   method) from within a Struts or WebWork action. No "plug-ins" are
>   involved, so no dedicated integration is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That means that if you don't want to use Spring MVC use a [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) to bootstrap an WebApplicationContext in the ServletContext. Something like this:

```
<!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

And then use [WebApplicationContextUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html) method [getRequiredWebApplicationContext(ServletContext sc)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getRequiredWebApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) (or other many ways) to get the WebApplicationContext and get access to your Spring Beans.

You can do this in any part of your application (as long as you can get a ServletContext). This means that you don't have to integrate Spring to other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

servlet context is the root of your web application directory. Everything else is given reference relative to it. Context loader listener is secod way of loading spring context, first being by use of dispatcher servlet.

**Application Context** is the container initialized by a **ContextLoaderListener** or **ContextLoaderServlet**(dispatcher-servlet) defined in the web.xml